# jQuery Cookie setup to hold last session data

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a simple Advent calendar where users open doors on specific date.  I've set up a jQuery cookie but I'd like it to remember the users last session when returning, so the doors they opened are still open when they return - I have set up the cookie but it's not holding the data, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Link: http://p3.katecooperuk.com

Door Opening - Selecting random image

```
$('.doors').click(function () {

    if (today.getMonth() !== 11) {
        return;
    }

    if ($(this).attr('id') <= 'dec' + (day + 10)) { // make it 11th Dec for testing

        // Select Random Image
        var doorImage = getRandomImage(calendarImg); 

        // Change background image of door that was clicked
        $(this).css('background-image', doorImage);

        return;  
    }

    // Show image telling user to come back
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/images/come_back.png)');

});
```

jQuery Cookie Setup

```
// Create Cookie - Expires in 40 days
$.cookie('door_cookie', '1', { expires: 30, path: '/' });

// Read Cookie
$.cookie('door_cookie'); // => "the_value"
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => undefined

$.cookie(); // => { "the_cookie": "the_value", "...remaining": "cookies" }

// Returns true when cookie was found, false when no cookie was found...
//$.removeCookie('the_cookie', { path: '/' });

$.cookie.raw = true;

$.cookie.json = true;
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the cookie code you used but this library worked with local storage: https://github.com/jarednova/jquery-total-storage and did the trick in a project of mine where I needed to store values.

Comment: Where is the code of the cookie read/write?